# Formato de fechas en Java

Tags: java, poo, java-ee, java-8, formato

tengo un problema con el formato de la fecha en el lenguaje java, deseo darle formato en **DD/MM/YYYY** pero no me permite, me lo formatea como **MM/DD/YYYY**. He intentado con el

> new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(getFecha())

Pero no me deja.
Este es el codigo:

```
for (InfoTarjeta t : list) {
                tblImpresion.addItem(
                        new Object[] { t.getRut(), t.getDv(), t.getApellidoPaterno(), t.getApellidoMaterno(),
                                t.getNombres(), t.getNumeroTarjeta(), t.getTipoProducto().getDescripcion(),
                                t.getTipoSolicitud().getDescripcion(), new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(t.getFechaEmision()), t.getNumeroAutentia() },
                        null);
            }
```

Alguien sabe sobre una posible solución en Java?
    gracias.

Comment: y cual es el formato original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El objeto Date se puede convertir a cualquier formato de cadena usando un `SimpleDateFormat` ver el siguiente ejemplo, que va a construir una representación de cadena de la fecha en el formato dd/MM/yyyy, que parece ser el formato que busca.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String fechaFormato = formatFecha.format(t.getFechaEmision());
```

En tu caso debería funcionar algo así.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (InfoTarjeta t : list) {
                    tblImpresion.addItem(
                            new Object[] { t.getRut(), t.getDv(), t.getApellidoPaterno(), t.getApellidoMaterno(),
                                    t.getNombres(), t.getNumeroTarjeta(), t.getTipoProducto().getDescripcion(),
                                    t.getTipoSolicitud().getDescripcion(), formatFecha.format(t.getFechaEmision()), t.getNumeroAutentia() },
                            null);
                }
```

o

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String fechaFormato = formatFecha.format(t.getFechaEmision());

        for (InfoTarjeta t : list) {
                        tblImpresion.addItem(
                                new Object[] { t.getRut(), t.getDv(), t.getApellidoPaterno(), t.getApellidoMaterno(),
                                        t.getNombres(), t.getNumeroTarjeta(), t.getTipoProducto().getDescripcion(),
                                        t.getTipoSolicitud().getDescripcion(), fechaFormato , t.getNumeroAutentia() },
                                null);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error al realizar la conversión

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(t.getFechaEmision())
```

De realizarse de esta forma:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(FORMATO INICIAL).format(new SimpleDateFormat(FORMATO DESEADO).parse(FECHA A CONVERTIR)));
```

#### Convertir fecha de un formato a otro en Java.

pongo como ejemplo este método que recibe el formato de entrada, de salida y el string con la fecha a convertir. Puedes también definir un `LOCALE` por ejemplo:

```
  public static final Locale LOCALE_MX = new Locale("es", "MX");
```

y este sería el método:

```
public static String dateFormatter(String inputFormat, String outputFormat, String inputDate){
      //Define formato default de entrada.   
      String input = inputFormat.isEmpty()? "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" : inputFormat; 
      //Define formato default de salida.
      String output = outputFormat.isEmpty()? "d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy" : outputFormat;
    String outputDate = inputDate;
    try {
        outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(output, LOCALE_MX).format(new SimpleDateFormat(input, LOCALE_MX).parse(inputDate));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("dateFormatter(): " + e.getMessage());           
    }
    return outputDate;
}
```

---

Estos son ejemplos de como usar el método, donde defino el formato que tiene mi fecha original "MM/dd/yyyy", el formato que deseo obtener "dd/MM/yyyy" y la fecha que deseo cambiar de formato:

```
   System.out.println("FECHA :" + dateFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy", "05/03/2017"));
```

obtendría :

```
FECHA: 03/05/2017
```

otro ejemplo:

```
    System.out.println("FECHA: " + dateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","dd/MM/yyyy", "2017-05-03 12:24:34"));
```

en el cual obtendrías el formato que deseas :

```
FECHA: 03/05/2017
```

incluso puedes modificar el formato de salida:

```
 System.out.println("FECHA: " + dateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy", "2017-05-03 12:24:34"));
```

y obtendrías:

```
FECHA: 3 de mayo del 2017
```